# What configuration settings that need to be changed when I switch from stand-alone version to multi-node version in Apache IoTDB 1.2.2 version?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently using the stand-alone version of Version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB installed by docker. My data has already been mounted, if I want to upgrade to distributed multi-node later, can I directly access multiple nodes? Or are there any configuration settings I need to change to switch to this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation of Apache IoTDB distinguishes between stand-alone version and scalable single-node version. The main setting difference is on `config_node_consensus_protocol_class` and `schema_region_consensus_protocol_class`, when stand-alone version is set to `Simple`, and single-node version is set to `Ratis`. Also, for `data_region_consensus_protocol_class`, stand-alone version is set to `Simple`, and single-node version is set to `IoT`. Therefore, if you want to switch to single-node version in the future, you need to also change these settings.